# Error when adding highchartsjs to Vue3 app

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 and added highchartsjs according to the docs.  I am getting this error:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "highcharts"

    node_modules/highcharts-vue/dist/highcharts-vue.min.js:1:90:
      1 │ ...?module.exports=e(require("highcharts"),require("vue")):"functio...
        ╵                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "highcharts" as external to exclude it from the bundle,
  which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a
  try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

I tried excluding it from bundle as suggested but it's not working:

vite.config.js

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['highcharts'],
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: @BAR But why would you externalize `highcharts`? Your project is clearly missing the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding `highcharts` via `optimizeDeps.exclude` would clear the error, but that would defeat your ultimate goal of using `highcharts` in your project. You'll notice that after using that config, your project still is not able to import `highcharts`. The error is indicating that your project is missing that dependency.

The solution would be to install `highcharts`:

```
npm install -S highcharts
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-hightcharts-vue)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['highcharts'],
  }
})
```